# Is the Ethrog upside down?

Tags: sukkah, lulav-etrog-arba-minim

I have a question regarding waving the lulav and ethrog. The mesorah ([sukkah 45b](https://www.sefaria.org/Sukkah.45b.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), [Mishneh Brurah 651:16](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.651.16?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) tells us to wave/hold the arba minim in the direction that it grows. But the tradition is to hold ethrog with the point up even though this is not the way it is grown from the tree. Does anyone have a reasoning behind this?
Thank you.

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9105/how-do-etrogs-grow-pitom-up-or-pitom-down

Comment: @rosends  The answers answer this question...

Comment: @rosends that link helped thank you.