# Orientation of Esrog relative to person versus relative to ground

Tags: halacha-theory, lulav-etrog-arba-minim

This question was originally going to be saved for Purim Torah in Jest, but after thinking about it, I feel this can have practical ramifications.

How does one hold an Esrog before making the Bracha 'Al Netilas Lulav' while the person is upside down, like on [monkey bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jungle_gym)? The core of this question is, does the Mitzvah get fulfilled based on the orientation of the Esrog relative to the person, relative to the Arbah Minim, or relative to the ground?

Comment: wait till you see this https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9105/759

Comment: probably relevant is I heard that the Aruch LaNer in a teshuva addresses using an esrog from Australia in Europe. It grew facing down relative to where he is standing. He ended up ruling that it goes relative to how he is standing.

Comment: @robev Don't you mean where he is standing, as in, how it would have grown if it had grown locally?

Comment: @N.T. yes sorry

Comment: Good. I thought it was obvious it goes relative to the ground, but I wanted to be sure.

Comment: @robev, they asked the question when they tried making California esrog groves.